# Polygon on Raster query in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I need to perform a polygon on raster cookie-cut and pixel sum using GeoServer.  The polygon (GeoJSON) and raster are both in WGS84 (4326).  The raster is a very large GeoTIFF population raster published with GeoServer.   I have two questions:

1. How to do the entire operation in GeoServer?
2. Alternatively, how to query the raw pixel values from the rectangular extent of the polygon (minx, miny, maxx, maxy), and I can do the pixel in/out sum analysis myself.

I have tried WMS queries and WCS queries but cannot find a way to request the raw pixel values rather than a PNG rendered result.  I have also tried some WPS sample queries, with no success.  I'm not seeing much from Google on polygon-on-raster statistics.  Is this entire query possible in GeoServer?  Or is at least fetching a rectangular area of raw pixels from the GeoTIFF from GeoServer possible?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

To fetch a rectangle of pixels as a GeoTiff you would need to use a WCS request. The easiest way to define one of those is using the [WCS Request generator](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wcs/requestbuilder.html) - for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><GetCoverage version="1.0.0" service="WCS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wcs" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/1.0.0/getCoverage.xsd">
  <sourceCoverage>nurc:Pk50095</sourceCoverage>
  <domainSubset>
    <spatialSubset>
      <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:32633">
        <gml:pos>347649.93086859107 5176214.082539256</gml:pos>
        <gml:pos>370725.976428591 5196961.352859256</gml:pos>
      </gml:Envelope>
      <gml:Grid dimension="2">
        <gml:limits>
          <gml:GridEnvelope>
            <gml:low>0 0</gml:low>
            <gml:high>545 490</gml:high>
          </gml:GridEnvelope>
        </gml:limits>
        <gml:axisName>E</gml:axisName>
        <gml:axisName>N</gml:axisName>
      </gml:Grid>
    </spatialSubset>
  </domainSubset>
  <output>
    <crs>EPSG:32633</crs>
    <format>GeoTIFF</format>
  </output>
</GetCoverage>
```

To extract values of a raster bounded by a polygon you can use a WPS request to crop to a polygon and then sum the pixels yourself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>ras:CropCoverage</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1">
            <ows:Identifier>nurc:Pk50095</ows:Identifier>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
              <ows:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32633">
                <ows:LowerCorner>347649.93086859107 5176214.082539256</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>370725.976428591 5196961.352859256</ows:UpperCorner>
              </ows:BoundingBox>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>cropShape</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/wkt"><![CDATA[POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2,......))]]></wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="image/tiff">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Or you could write your own [custom process](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html) to carry out the whole process in one go.

Comment: I had some further questions as I was trying to work this through, but I deleted them as I found my way,  Your answer above is quite correct.   For WGS84 queries, replace the  32633 with 4326.  Use the geoserver Demo Requests and for the rectangle example above choose WCS_getCoverage_2.0.1_format_geotiff.url in the the Request drop-down. That will show you the URL and GET parameters needed,

Comment: For the second cropShape example use Demo Requests and scroll to the bottom for any WPS request to find that you only need the URL myserver/geoserver/wps with no GET parameters and indeed send as a POST request.  In Postman I used geoserver/wps as the URL, Content-Type=text/xml and put the above XML (with my projection 4326 and BoundingBox and POLYGON x,y values).  In Postman you have to go to use Save Response after the query or you won't see any results, but they are there.

Comment: I have two final questions.   1) I've looked everywhere for the API parameters and XML content references and I couldn't find anything like what I needed for this.  Where can I find that info?    2) Where do I send the Starbucks gift card?   The above was a life saver!!    Thanks Ian!

Comment: just accept the answer if it helped you :-) - you could maybe take the [tour] to see how the site works