# GeoServer, Get Raster Data values with Polygon Points

Tags: geoserver, wps

I have a Geoserver instance deployed, with some vector and some raster layers configured. One of the vector layers has country delimitations, and I want to use them to retrieve the RASTER data of one of these countries (all the points, in order to calculate the average).

I have something working, but i don't trust it a lot, it is supposed to return all the points, but if I check it manually, some of them are missing.

But it seems to be close to the solution. So there is the problem:

- seems to be missing some values,
- it takes 15 seconds to retrieve the data for some countries.

Is this the proper way to implement that? Should I precalculate the averages and store them in another database? Is there a better approach?

solution guide from: [Polygon on Raster query in GeoServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69261614/polygon-on-raster-query-in-geoserver)